# Taylor expansion of composite function f(g(x))

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose I have two continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, is it possible that I expand $f(g(x))$ at $g(0)$ using a series of $g(x)$?

For example, is it possible that I write:
\begin{equation}
f(g(x))=f(g(0))+f'(g(0))g(x)+\frac{f''(g(0))}{2}g^2(x)+\cdots
\end{equation}

In my case, $g(x)=e^{-x^2} (0\leq x \leq1)$. I don't have an analytic expression for $f(x)$ but I can evaluate it numerically and I know it is monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

See [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). You need the derviatives of $f$ at $g(0)$.